# Embed not updating

Tags: embeds

We have an embed that shows latest posts on the home page.

```
{embed="/embeds/.sidebar_articles}
```

This works. But when I go to change anything in it, such as filtering the posts or even just making a text change nothing updates on the live website.

```
{if segment_1 == "section"}

    {if segment_3 == ""}

            {!-- ============================================

            DISPLAY A LIST OF MOST READ ARTICLES FROM THE
            CURRENT CATEGORY. FOR HOME PAGE- DISPLAY ACROSS
            ALL CATEGORIES.

            ============================================= --}

            <div class="art-preview">
            {exp:channel:entries
                channel="sections"
                limit="3"
                dynamic="off"
                {if segment_2}category="{segment_2_category_id}"{/if}
                orderby="view_count_one" }

                {if count == "1"}
                    {if segment_2 == ""}
                    <h3>Most read stories</h3>
                    {if:else}
                    <h3>Popular in <span data-source="{segment_2}">{segment_2_category_name}</span></h3>
                    {/if}
                {/if}
                <a href="/section/{segment_2}/{url_title}">
                    <div class="preview">
                    {if article_cover_image}
                        {exp:ce_img:pair src="{article_cover_image}" width="160" height="160" crop="yes"}
                        <img src="{made}" alt="">
                        {/exp:ce_img:pair}
                    {if:else}
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/160x160">
                    {/if}
                        <h4>{title}</h4>
                        <div class="meta">Last edited {edit_date format='%d/%m/%y'}</div>
                        {!-- <div class="lead"> {article_lead} </div> --} 
                    </div>
                </a>
            {/exp:channel:entries}                          
            </div> <!-- /art-preview -->


    {if:else}

            {!-- ============================================

            DISPLAY A LIST OF ENTRIES FROM THE SAME CATEGORY
            AS THE CURRENT ARTICLE.

            ============================================= --}

            <div class="art-preview">
            {exp:channel:entries
                channel="sections"
                limit="3"
                dynamic="off"
                {if segment_2}category="{segment_2_category_id}"{/if}
                url_title="not {segment_3}"}

                {if count == "1"}<h3>Related</h3>{/if}

                <a href="/section/{segment_2}/{url_title}">
                    <div class="preview">
                    {if article_cover_image}
                        {exp:ce_img:pair src="{article_cover_image}" width="160" height="160" crop="yes"}
                        <img src="{made}" alt="">
                        {/exp:ce_img:pair}
                    {if:else}
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/160x160">
                    {/if}
                        <h4>{title}</h4>
                        <div class="meta">Last edited {edit_date format='%d/%m/%y'}</div>
                        {!-- <div class="lead"> {article_lead} </div> --}
                    </div>
                </a>

            {/exp:channel:entries}                      
            </div> <!-- /art-preview -->

    {/if}

{if:else}


            <div class="art-preview">
            {exp:channel:entries
                channel="sections"
                limit="3"
                dynamic="off"
                {if segment_1 == ""}orderby="view_count_one"{/if}}

                {if count == "1"}
                    {if segment_1 == ""}
                    <h3>Most read stories</h3>
                    {if:else}
                    <h3>Latest News</h3>
                    {/if}
                {/if}
                <a href="/section/{categories}{category_url_title}{/categories}/{url_title}">
                    <div class="preview">
                    {if article_cover_image}
                        {exp:ce_img:pair src="{article_cover_image}" width="160" height="160" crop="yes"}
                        <img src="{made}" alt="">
                        {/exp:ce_img:pair}
                    {if:else}
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/160x160">
                    {/if}
                        <h4>{title}</h4>
                        <div class="meta">Last edited {edit_date format='%d/%m/%y'}</div>
                        {!-- <div class="lead"> {article_lead} </div> --}
                    </div>
                </a>
            {/exp:channel:entries}                          
            </div> <!-- /art-preview -->


{/if}
```

I've tried pasting this code direct into the template, it shows up but again doesn't show any changes made.

Comment: In what way do you change the code: FTP or do you change the code in the template file in the cms? Is cache enabled on .sidebar_articles?

Comment: I'm doing it through the CMS. Not sure if cached is enabled as the developer has set it to DO NOT CHANGE

Comment: To check the cache goto the template itself (.sidebar_articles), open up the Preferences Accordion at the bottom and let us know the state of the "Enable Caching" field. Also (appologies if you've tried this, you don't say) are you sure it's not  browser cache? Go InPrivate/InCognito or Force refresh (Ctrl+F5) a few times just in case its your browser caching it!!

Comment: Caching is not enabled. I've checked the site in another browser after the change but nothing changes. Have also force refreshed as you suggested

Comment: You can try to check the option "save revision as File" and update.

Comment: Another option is that the file where the embed is in has cache enabled.

Comment: I've checked the parent file and caching isn't enabled there either. There doesn't seem to be an option to save revision. Is this in the preferences?

Comment: It is an option you can enable. If it is not there beneath the template, it won't be the solution.

Now I see you are missing a quote in the embed. Could you try this:

{embed="embeds/.sidebar_articles"}

Comment: Are you using any caching solution such as CE Cache or CloudFlare services? Also, you should create a temporary template to do testing in, and you should really break down your code there. Make it a reaaaal simple {exp:channel:entires} tag with no segment conditionals, and see if you can get the page updating.

Comment: I have created a new embed and added this to the page, and changed the heading. This appears fine. But if I then go to edit this it changes in the CMS but not on the live site. Is it to do with privileges maybe? I don't believe we're using any caching solution.

Comment: Regardless of your cache setting, make sure you do this: https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/tools/data/clear_cached_data_files.html and clear all cache. Then try again (sorry to hammer on the cache thing, gotta be sure)

Comment: No problem, any help is appreciated. I've done that but hasn't solved the issue.

Comment: I inherited a site where similar happened. Turned out the template path was referencing the dev folder not live. Fixed the paths and it came good.

Answer (score 0):

Your embed tag syntax looks wrong, missing closing quotes, also you don't need the first slash:

```
Wrong
{embed="/embeds/.sidebar_articles}

Correct
{embed="embeds/.sidebar_articles"}
```

Comment: Thanks. Balloonatic had already spotted that. Corrected and didn't change anything. Just tried removed slash and it brings an error warning up saying it is needed